# Adding state value to JSON object or context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I currently have a context that contains a JS object. I want to be able to add a useState value to this object so that I can later use useEffect on the context to see if the state value has changed.

Here, I have my context:

```
//This exported as SortContext
export default React.createContext({
    sortKeys: [],
    setSortKeys: () => {}
})
```

And here is where I'd like to use the sortKeys array:

```
export default function useObjectListSort (objectList, sortFunctionMap) {

    const sortContext = useContext(SortContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        //Do something when sortKeys gets updated.
    }, sortContext.sortKeys)
```

And this is a component I made to initialize the context:

```
export default function SortBlock ({children}) {

    const [sortKeyList, setSortKeyList] = useState([])

    const sortContextConfig = {
        sortKeys: sortKeyList,
        setSortKeys: (newKeys) => setSortKeyList(newKeys)
    }

    return (
        <SortContext.Provider value={sortContextConfig}>
            {children}
        </SortContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

What I would expect is that using the my SortBlock component, and calling the setSortKeys function would update the sortKeyList state, and then the useEffect statement would trigger.

For example:

```
<SortContext.Consumer>
    {sortContext => {
        <button onClick={()=>sortContext.setSortKeys(['myKey'])}> Set Keys </button>
    }}
</SortContext.Consumer>
```

Unfortunately, the useEffect is not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the issue. I used the useObjectSortList hook in the same component that I used to initialize the SortBlock. This means that it falls outside of the scope of my context.